# Using the variable of a function in another function

Tags: python

I have the following functions to calculate two different things:

```
def LCM(X0, a, c, m, n):  #Generates "n" numbers of random numbers# with given parameters.
    X = []
    X.append(X0)
    for i in range(n):
        X.append(float((a*X[i]+c) % m))
        X[i] = X[i]/m
    del X[0]
    X[n-1] = X[n-1]/m

    plt.hist(X)
    plt.title("LCM Frequency Histogram")
    plt.show()
    print "For this example, the LCM generated a good quality uniform distribution." 
    print "However, it should be also noted that every 2000 generations," 
    print "the numbers are repeated."
    return X[:10] #Show only the first 10 values of the list.

def exponential(lambdavalue):
    Z =[]
    for i in range(10000):
        Z.append(float(-(1/lambdavalue)*math.log(1-X[i])))
    plt.hist(Z)
    plt.title("Exponential Frequency Histogram")
    plt.show()
    return Z[:10] #Show only the first 10 values of the list.
```

In the first function, I calculate the variable `X` and in the second I find `Z` based on X and plot its histogram. I am not able to understand how I can pass the variable `X` to the second function. I am running following for the first function:

```
LCM(27, 17, 9, 10000, 10000)
```

and this for the second:

```
exponential(10)
```

I am also aware I can use some packages to make these things (LCM random generation and exp distr), however, I wanted to make something to practice.

Comment: you need to make the variable X global in the first function by using the 'global' keyword. i.e write global X at the very first line inside the first function before writing X=[ ]

Comment: To understand what is going on you might want to do some reading on the scope of variables in Python.  There are lots of tutorials but [this explanation](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) in the documentation is quite good.

Comment: @Bill,  I like [section 9.1 and 9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) of the Tutorial and [4.2 Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of the Language Reference

Comment: @Bill, and wwii thank you so much. I am having one more issue with the histogram in the second function. With the given parameters, I have 6320 values between 0 and 0.1 (including 0.1), 2325 between 0.1 and 0.2, 855 values between 0.2 and 0.3, and so on. However, the histogram does not reflect these numbers correctly. If you may take a look at it, I would really appreciate for your time.

Comment: @user8028576 , since you have solved the question that is the subject of this post, you should post a new question about the histogram issue.  Also, be more specific about the problem. "the histogram does not reflect these numbers" is too vague.  Show the revised code and ideally show an image of the histogram and explain what you expected to see. Thanks.

Comment: Another piece of advice if you don't mind.  It is good practice not to include output such as print and plot inside a function that is primarily for calculation since it limits its use. Suggest you put the printing and plotting statements after the function definitions in the main body of the code. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are returning the X values from the first function you could pass them to the second function as follows:

```
X = LCM(27, 17, 9, 10000, 10000)
Z = exponential(X, 10)
```

You just need to add an argument to `exponential` for the X values.

Comment: `You just need to add a...` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @wwii. I just [learned something](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-argument-vs-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value returned from the LCM function into a variable so you do-

```
x = lcm(27, 17, 9, 10000, 10000)
```

And then you pass the value of x as an argument into the exponential function as -

```
x = exponential(10)
```

Another way is you can declare a global variable X=[ ] outside both your function and you can use them in both of your functions. Without passing it as an argument in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable in other functions by declaring it as global in each function that assigns to it:

```
x = 0
def f():
    x = 1
f()
print x #=>0
```

and expect 1. Instead, you need do declare that you intend to use the global x:

```
x = 0
def f():
    global x
    x = 1
f()
print x #=>1
```

I hope it will help you. Or at least get you closer to solution.